# Deactivate Pagination Tooltip

Tags: javascript, tabulator

we are using Tabulator.js 4.7 to display regulatory data in a table. We use the pagination feature.
The table works very well, unfortunately there is a visual error with the tooltip on the pagination buttons (see screenshot in the bottom right):
[image]

Unfortunately sometimes the tooltips - once you hover over them - do not disappear anymore. So you get a bulk of overlapping, persistant tooltips.
This error appears in Google Chrome as well as in Firefox.

Do you know this error? Do you know a solutions to solve this issue? If not, is there a possibility to deactivate tooltips on the pagination buttons? In the tabulator.js documentation we only found the attribute, to deactivate tooltips in the table.

Best regards and thank you,
Gerrit

Answer (score 0):

Tabulator uses the standard browser tooltips so the functionality of each individual tooltip is outside of its control.

Though looking at that screenshot those tooltips look non standard so it is possible you have a 3rd party library or browser extension that is interfering with them.

All the tooltips are set in the localization data, so you could easily override them with empty strings:

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    langs:{
        "default":{
            "pagination":{
                "first":"",
                "first_title":"",
                "last":"",
                "last_title":"",
                "prev":"",
                "prev_title":"",
                "next":"",
                "next_title":"",
                "all":"",
            },
        }
    },
});
```